# How to get data in JSON from laravel web page?

Tags: json, laravel

I have done a web page using laravel. This web page is to store courses with sudents and some data. Now I`d like to get information as JSON but I don´t know how to do it.

Here´s my funtion show in my controller to show all the students stored in a course:

```
public function show(Course $course)
    {
        $students = $course->students()->get();
        return view('Course.show',compact('students','course'));
    }
```

The url that appears in my navigatio bar is: http://tfg.test/courses/25 because I´m doing it locally. Now, if I use Postman to make a get request to that url I receive the whole html page, but no JSON data. I don´t know how this is done.

I have tried doing this:

```
public function show(Course $course)
    {
        
        $students = $course->students()->get();
        
        return response()->json($students, 200);
        /* return view('Course.show',compact('students','course')); */
        
    }
```

And I get the JSON but I don`t go to the view in the web page

This is my route in web.php:

```
Route::resource('courses', CourseController::class);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you need to return the view **OR** return `JSON`, depending on the Request. Laravel has a `->ajax()` method you can use to see if this is an AJAX request (i.e. expecting `JSON`) or a non-AJAX request (i.e. expecting the `view()` to render):

```php
public function show(Request $request, Course $course) {
  $students = $course->students; // `->students` is shorthand for `->students()->get()`

  if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json($students, 200);
  }
        
  return view('Course.show', compact('students', 'course'));
}
```

Don't forget to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to the top of your Controller too.

Now, when navigating to `http://tfg.test/courses/25`, you'll get the `view()` rendered, but when making an AJAX request, you'll get `$students` back as `JSON`.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis for your answer. I have tried it and when I use the web page I get the view but if I use postman and I make a get request to http://tfg.test/courses/25 I keep getting the html file and not the JSON.

Comment: Make sure the Postman request includes the correct headers; `$request->ajax()` will return `true` or `false` depending on those. I forget which one specifically though...